# Not signal between openvpn server on linux and windows client

Tags: linux, windows, iptables, vpn, openvpn

I have Centos 6. My openvpn server.conf:

```
local xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx
port 1194
proto udp
dev tap
ca /etc/openvpn/keys2/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys2/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys2/server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh /etc/openvpn/keys2/dh2048.pem
server 192.168.112.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
mute 20
```

My client1.ovpn:

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

I have answer on my client1:

```
Fri Sep 16 14:38:14 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.12 i686-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [
PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Aug 23 2016
Fri Sep 16 14:38:14 2016 Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7) 32bit
Fri Sep 16 14:38:14 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.09
Fri Sep 16 14:38:14 2016 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has
been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Fri Sep 16 14:38:14 2016 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Fri Sep 16 14:38:14 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]62.64.104.228:1194
```

And i can't connect to our local network from client1.
Firewall is disabled. ipv4 forward is enabled. Where i have error ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you really just post all of the information someone needs to connect to your VPN?

Comment: i have second config. tap1.p2p.config. to our other factory. but in it config & in my current config defferent ports.

Comment: You posted your server IP, and client private keys. Did you obfuscate or change the keys? If not, anyone could take this information and connect to your VPN.